# Liquibase stuck on Computed checksum

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase

Running Liquibase with Java/Spring against a Snowflake database.  The first deployment works fine, I let Liquibase create the DatabaseChangeLogTable and the DatabaseChangeLogLockTable.  They get created, and written to and the database objects are created.

The second time I try to run it, it will acquire the change log lock, but then sit for a long time at liquibase.util : Computed checksum for xxxx.  Then timeout after 5 minutes (due to other config settings).   If I drop the DatabaseChangeLogTable and DatabaseChangeLogLockTable (interactively), and update the lock status to false, it works fine again.  Any ideas on why it can't seem to finish when the DatabaseChangeLogTable and DatabaseChangeLogLockTable are already there?  When I log into the database using the same credentials that Liquibase is using, I can select and update those tables just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using clearChecksums?
clearCheckSums clears all checksums and nullifies the MD5SUM column of the DATABASECHANGELOG table so they will be re-computed on the next database update.Changesets that have been deployed will have their checksums re-computed, and pending changesets will be deployed. For more details about this approach, please visit [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/clearchecksums.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I can try updating the checksum column to null in a final script on the first run, but I don't have access to command line liquibase commands in this environment.  And the fact that dropping the changelog table effectively clears the checksums anyway, I am not certain this will help, but I will give it a try.

Comment: You can clear checksums through your java code as well, you do not necessarily need it to be executed through CLI. Regarding dropping the changelog table is not a good practice. Instead clearing the checksum column should be preferred. Sure please give it a try and let us know if you encounter any issues.